# Is the sentence I ‘created’ correct?

Tags: word-choice

Could anyone tell me whether the following sentence is correct? I don’t know why, but the first part sounds a bit strange to me.

‘Because she gave him enchanted Turkish delight, an enchanted hot drink and a false promise, the White Witch managed to trick Edmund into betraying his brother and his two sisters.’

Comment: There should be a comma after _drink_.

Comment: Okay, thanks! But could you explain me why?

Comment: Because you're listing three things (candy, drink, promise), and they should have an intonation (represented by the comma) separating them. As you say, it sounds a bit strange, when you hear it, if the intonation isn't there. That's the dead horse that Lynne Truss beats in her book about commas.

Comment: Is it just me, or are you reading C.S. Lewis in your created sentences?  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529712/was-used-for-tricking-was-used-to-trick

Shoots and leaves.

Comment: That comma is known as the Oxford comma and its use is a matter of style. Using the Oxford comma is typically recommended because its omission can cause amiguity in the writing, but it's not fully ungrammatical to fail to use it. Many writers do not use it. C'est la vie.